# specifying images in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to experiment with the twitter-bootstrap example

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html

If you go to the page, you will see there are three light circles with 140X140 written in it.

I am trying to have an image in that circle..

The following is the relevant code

```
<div class="span4">
              <img class="img-circle" data-src="holder.js/140x140">
              <h2>foobar</h2>
              <p>Elaborate</p>
              <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!-- /.span4 -->
```

How can i achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply uses the `border-radius` style. The image is actually a square image, but the `border-radius` style trims the corners to make it a circle.

```
.img-circle {
-webkit-border-radius: 500px;
-moz-border-radius: 500px;
border-radius: 500px;
}
```

I'd recommend you not load an image to do this though. You can do the same thing with a div like this:

HTML

```
<div class="img-circle"></div>
```

CSS

```
.img-circle {
background:#555;
width: 140px;
height: 140px;
-webkit-border-radius: 500px;
-moz-border-radius: 500px;
border-radius: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not replace the image with your own one rather than insert one into it

instead of-

```
<img class="img-circle" data-src="holder.js/140x140">
```

this

```
<img class="img-circle" data-src="yourImage.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Holder.js:
Holder renders image placeholders entirely on the client side.

http://imsky.github.io/holder/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm a bit late, try changing data-src="" to
src="" then put the img link/name in between the " " 's